# INDEX / MATCH / VLOOKUP Assistance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The below table is the first 29 rows in an XLSX I'm working on, which basically aims to calculate the costs of exported call data.

The data in the table below is the result of population from a PowerShell script, which combines Rate Data from a CSV (to calculate call charges) with Call Data from the customer's daily call stats in another CSV.

**Rate Data:**

Column F [Destination] contains every known Country Code.
Column E [Rate] contains a Rate value for each Country Code in column F, which will be used to calculate the call cost at the end.

**Call Export Data:**
Column C [Callee Number] contains the original phone number that was called (Callee).
Column H [Callee Country Code] takes first few digits of the number in Column C for the next step.

**Required goal that I'm quite frankly stuck on:**

Column I is what I'm working on.

I need a formula that effectively looks for the dialled country code in Column H and looks for the country code that's the MOST SIMILAR to it (Doesn't need to be exact) in Column F. Once found, I need it to return the value on the same row, in Column E [Rate].

Column I should then be populated with the correct Rate for the Number in Column C / H.

Formula's I've tried:

`=INDEX($A$2:$K$100000,VLOOKUP(H2,$F$2:$F$100000,5,TRUE))`

`=INDEX($G$2:$G$100000,MATCH(H2,$F$2:$F$100000,0))`

I'm not great with Excel but and I'm sure using 100000 to select the whole column is poor practise.

Thanks for any help :)

| Start time | Customer | Callee Number | Country | Rate | Destination | Duration (Minutes) | Callee Country Code | Rate for call | Cost of call |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-01T07:25:30.5190000Z | Name1 | +44*** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 93 | 0 | 44 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:05:52.6250000Z | Name2 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9320 | 0.383333333 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:33:49.6530000Z | Name3 | +441509****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9321 | 0.7 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:35:18.5300000Z | Name4 | +441509****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9322 | 0.766666667 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:43:45.3300000Z | Name5 | +447976****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9323 | 1.85 | 447 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:47:29.9630000Z | Name6 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9324 | 2.533333333 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T08:57:43.2680000Z | Name7 | +447875****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9325 | 3.633333333 | 447 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T09:04:42.8230000Z | Name8 | +441212****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9326 | 4.916666667 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T09:15:32.7220000Z | Name9 | +441923****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9327 | 1.9 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T09:30:36.4750000Z | Name10 | +441923****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9328 | 5.8 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T09:58:12.8380000Z | Name11 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9370 | 0.516666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T10:03:04.1270000Z | Name12 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9375 | 13.51666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T10:27:49.6090000Z | Name13 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9377 | 2.716666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T11:04:21.7850000Z | Name14 | +442476****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9378 | 1.6 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T11:13:31.9810000Z | Name15 | +442070****** | AFGHANISTAN | 1.415 | 9379 | 9.816666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T11:46:53.4730000Z | Name16 | +442476****** | ALAND ISLANDS |  | 247 | 0.283333333 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T11:47:14.9110000Z | Name17 | +442476****** | ALBANIA | 0.537 | 355 | 0.866666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:30:38.4380000Z | Name18 | +442476****** | ALBANIA | 0.537 | 3554 | 0.25 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:30:59.5190000Z | Name19 | +442476****** | ALBANIA | 0.537 | 35567 | 0.283333333 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:31:34.3300000Z | Name20 | +442476****** | ALBANIA | 0.537 | 35568 | 0.283333333 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:35:20.8430000Z | Name21 | +442476****** | ALBANIA | 0.537 | 35569 | 0.3 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:37:36.5550000Z | Name22 | +442476****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 213 | 1.366666667 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T12:42:07.9660000Z | Name23 | +447723****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21321 | 1.466666667 | 447 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T13:13:37.7610000Z | Name24 | +441926****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21355 | 3.283333333 | 441 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T13:44:57.3190000Z | Name25 | +442476****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21356 | 0.15 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T13:46:39.2640000Z | Name26 | +442476****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21366 | 0.15 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T13:58:14.1340000Z | Name27 | +442476****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21369 | 6.2 | 442 |  |  |
| 2020-09-01T13:58:30.5560000Z | Name28 | +442476****** | ALGERIA | 0.537 | 21377 | 0.583333333 | 442 |  |  |

Comment: At first I thought making a list of unique callee country codes and index their rate to sort them from small to large and lookup the latest match, so it'll match regardless the number of digits, but I noticed all callee country codes are repeated per country and therefore not unique. Could you better describe what value you are trying to retrieve based on which condition(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Copied the table to a workbbok and figured out this code:

```
=IF(LEFT($C1;4)=$H1;INDEX($A$1:$I$28;ROW($H1);5);"")
```

This code checks, that if the first 4 digits of the phone number equals to the number in H column. If this is true then it gets the row number of the H and gets the value from E. If its false writes nothing.

I don't know if You mistyped the question, but I see no similarities between columns H and F.

> I need a formula that effectively looks for the dialled country code in Column H and looks for the country code that's the MOST SIMILAR to it (Doesn't need to be exact) in Column F.

So I made the code for Column C and H.

BUT theres is 1 downside to this code: You need to have exactly the first 4 digits in H column. It means You have to have H formed like this: +442; +447 etc.

Feel free to change the range and names of columns and rows to match Your Excel table.

Just a tip: if You want to select entire columns, You have to write **A:A;B:B** etc. into the formula. Or just click on the name of the column, and it inserts automatically. Same with rows.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions to improve your Excel:
In order to work well with Excel I would suggest you would use help columns with the required sub calculation, since no-one can understand lengthy formulas. Better yet: use small lookup tables for reference.
You need two sub columns: 1 for country code (extract that from the phone number) and 1 for rate.
So I would suggest to add a table with "Country Code" "Country Name" "Rate". It is going to be a small table and you can look you data up from there.

Please note the following:

1. A phone number is a string. It's not a number. Look at the cells in "Callee Number". Are they formatted as Numbers? Text? It's important to make sure they are formatted as TEXT. once they are, you can start manipulating them properly.
   [image: defining the cell as Text in Excel]
2. You're right, and as was noted, if you want to search an entire column, Just write F:F and don't use the start row - end row if there isn't really one. That's also a good reason to use small lookup table: Excel need to look for less data in order to find the information required.
3. Test your results in order to make sure that the VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH (or XLOOKUP, the new formula on the block) are doing what is expected of them :)